# google api console removed my registered apps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api-console

Few months ago i registered two android apps in Google developer console for using Google map  android API version 2.  Today  when i signed in to register another app i noticed that Google API console doesn't show my previous registered apps(in API access tab- information, key, API key owner etc). It shows nothing. Though my previous app's  maps are working fine.  Can anybody explain why that happened ? Thank you.

How can i get those registered app back ? i am fairly new in android development. A little help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like they have rolled up the screens a bit to reduce duplication. See the APIs & auth > Credentials, it now has credentials for all my Apps. I *think* this used to be per app, but I don't remember exactly.

Also the Consent Screen now has this, which may not have been there before either.

**Note:** This screen will be shown for all of your applications registered in this project.

As of today, the Google Documentation is still incorrect at https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#creatingdeletingprojects

It says...

To register a new application, do the following:

1. Go to the Google Cloud Console.
2. Select a project, or create a new one.
3. In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth. In the displayed list of APIs, make sure all the APIs you are using show a status of ON.
4. In the sidebar on the left, select Registered apps.

Number 4 no longer exists.

Answer (score 3):

Use the old console:

https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect

Had the same issue, trying to register YouTube Android Api
Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Google api console now changed or upgraded to Google cloud console. You can access all your projects here using the following link

https://cloud.google.com/console#/project

Comment: yes i noticed that.. but still my registered app are not showing either in cloud console or in the old console.

Comment: are you getting completely blank screen with option to create new project here?

Comment: yeah..just register new app button .. no previous registered app !!

Answer (score 0):

go to this link you will be able to use the old version of google console :

https://code.google.com/apis/console/#:?noredirect

New version is not working on Firefox (Ubuntu), it's working on Chrome :

https://cloud.google.com/console