# Google remove "Registered apps" section

Tags: android, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

Google removed the `Registered apps` section.

It must be really recent because I just seen it few weeks ago:

[image]

and now:

[image]

My problem is I need to register a new app to my project.

The documentation haven't been update `:-S`

But I have found two post about this , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670736/i-didnt-find-apis-auth-registered-apps-in-google-cloud-console) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566788/google-api-console-removed-my-registered-apps)

Is google forcing us to use a new project for Registered app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [issue with registration app in GCM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677709/issue-with-registration-app-in-gcm)

Comment: There's no need for a new project. They just changed the UI (again). See duplicate question and its answer in my other comment.

Comment: @Eran so creating a new key won't overwrite the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not a major change, user just need to create a `API Key`, that menu just no longer exist.