# Google Developers Console: how do I register a new application?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api#register_project) for Google's Analytics API.

The tutorial says "If you haven't already registered your application with the Google Developers Console, then set up a project and application in the Developers Console".

The documentation for the Developers Console says "A project consists of a set of applications...", which makes sense.

I'm able to create the project, but I don't see any way to create an application within that project. Both pieces of documentation linked above instruct me to click on "Registered apps" in the left sidebar, but there is no such link. (I believe these docs were written for an older version of the Console.)

On the recommendation of [another poster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20857915/3311358), I tried using the old Console instead, but I can't find any "Registered apps" link (or any other way to create an application) in that version, either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say whether you were doing this as a service account, web app, or installed app but this should get you pointed in the right direction for all of those.

And, Google radically changed the console UI.

The application gets created when you create the credentials for an application type.

[image]

If you created the project in the Google Console, select the project and follow the instructions in the tut you linked to:

> > 1. Go to the Google Developers Console.
> > 2. Select a project.
> > 3. In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth. In the displayed list of APIs, make sure all the APIs you are using show a status of ON.
> > 4. In the sidebar on the left, select Credentials.

**Add this step**: Click on the "Create New Client ID" button then select the application type.

> > In either case, you end up on the application's credentials page.
> >
> > To find your application's client ID and client secret, and set a redirect URI, expand the OAuth 2.0 Client ID section.
> >
> > Write down the values for each of these fields:
> >
> > Client ID
> >
> > Client secret

Comment: So, basically, each new Client ID that I create is an application?

Comment: @immersiontravis Correct.

Comment: Thanks. Google's products are full of weird wrinkles like this. Why can't they just *say* so in the documentation (or use more intuitive terminology in the app itself)?

Comment: @immersiontravis I agree. Also, the documentation never seems to keep up with the changes they make in their procedures.